# How to Scrape multiple URL's and Titles and save it into my Database where each URL matches the Title?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, puppeteer

I have the following problem: I would like to scrape the URL's and Title's of Lightnovel's I'm reading and insert it into my Database, while **each ChapterUrl matches the ChapterTitle.**

I would like **the endresult** structurely look like this in my Database :

```
LightNovel:{
  chapters:{
    chapter1:{
      chapterUrl: String,
      chapterTitle: String
      chapterUpdate: Date()
    },
    chapter2:{
      chapterUrl: String,
      chapterTitle: String
      chapterUpdate: Date()
    }, etc...
  }
}
```

I would like to have an Object structure like LightNovel.?chapters.?chapter1.?chapterUrl
So far i can scrape each title and url with these line's of code:

`let ChapterTitle = await page.$$eval('.div class .div class .div class a', a => a.map(title=> title.textContent.trim()));`

// Will get me the title and returns me an array of titles.

&&

`let ChapterUrl await page.$$eval('.div class .div class .div class a', ahref => ahref.map(link => link.href));`

// Will get me the Url and returns me an array of links

When i scrape these things individualy I get for each an array of content, and when inserting it into the Database it looks structurely like this:

chapters: object

chapterTitle: Array ( Array of every title)

chapterUrl: Array (Array of every link)

so far so good, I mean that is what I wrote in code in the end...

but i would like each scapred URL match the title, as mentioned above .

Question:
How would i need handle this problem in order to get my desired endresult?

I hope i could make myself understood and am grateful for any answer / help / guidance regarding this matter.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format the code in the question and remove excess whitespace from it. use the code formatting `{}` tool button and read more about formatting in the help link in the editor

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if make an array of `chapters` and push individual chapter to that array.

Below is one version of what can be done, you can modify it as to your need.

Keep in mind I'm using `for` loop because i wanted to keep things simple you can use high order array methods like `map,filter,reduce` to accomplish similar thing with less lines of code.

```js
let lightNovel={}
let ChapterTitleArray = ['title1', 'title2']
let ChapterURLArray = ['link1', 'link2']
let chapters = []

for (let i = 0; i < ChapterTitleArray.length; i++) {
  let chapter = {
    chapterTitle: ChapterTitleArray[i],
    chapterUrl: ChapterURLArray[i],
    chapterUpdate: new Date()
  }
  let key= `chapter ${i+1}`
  chapters.push({[key]:chapter})
}

lightNovel={chapters}

console.log(lightNovel)
```